# Croatia resident permit (Nomad) and Schengen days

Tags: schengen, permits

I have a question related to the validity of Schengen days. I’ve entered Croatia in Sep 2022 and applied for the Nomad visa (residence permit). Residence permit is valid from Nov 2022 till Nov 2023. When I obtained residence permit Croatia was not part of Schengen. Starting from 2023 Croatia is part of Schengen zone.

My residence permit expires in November 2023.

I have visa free Schengen access.

Do I still have valid Schengen days in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Since you **haven't** been a **visitor** in the Schengen Area in the **previous 180 days** (starting the day after the **residence permit** expires)

- you will have a **full** 90 days that can be used as a visitor in the Schengen Area

Any time spent in the Schengen Area in 2022 has expired.

When you finally leave the Schengen Area, show your residence permit card as proof that you were a resident until it expired.

Comment: Got it, thanks Mark. So as I understand, while I have my residence permit the Schengen days are not counting?

Comment: @Pipboy3k However it’s worth noting that as soon as the resident permit expires, your rights change (revert back to normal visitor rights), as work is no longer allowed for instance. And of course it is assumed you are a citizen from a country which has visa-free entry into Schengen.

Comment: @Pipboy3k While the residence permit is valid, you are a resident (and not a visitor).